# Double value being set to +Infinity or NaN

Tags: c#, double, infinity

I am currently making an AI that plays liars dice, and want to calculate the chance of a bid being true, so I am using this formula (with d = sum of all dices and n = my bet of how many equal dices are (like 4 2)): [Liars Dice Chances Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVvPr.png)

Only problem is the values get so long on the decimal end that it becomes +infinity or NaN if I try anything like Math.Round
If it helps this is the code(Players * 5 for the 5 dice each player has) :

```
ChanceOfTruth = 0
    for (int i = CurrentBid; i <= Players * 5; i++) 
        {
         ChanceOfTruth += (Factorial(Players * 5)/(Factorial(i)*Factorial(Players*5-i)))*Math.Pow(1f/6f,i)*Math.Pow(5f/6f,Players*5-i);   
         }
    public static double Factorial(double num) 
            { 
                for(int i = (int)num - 1; i > 0; i--) 
                {
                    num *= i;
                }
                return num;
            }
```

Comment: This needs to be tagged with a language, and you need to transfer your linked code screenshot to a verbatim code text block in the question.

Comment: like this? First Time using this website

Comment: Yes, that's great!

Comment: Some part of your equation is overflowing `double` - most likely the factorial. Break down your equation into parts and run it in the debugger to see where the overflow is occurring.

Comment: Highest value possible (for Factorial of 25 since only 5 players can play) is 1,5511210043331E+25 , so its not the factorial overflowing

Comment: Just a stylistic thing, but you might want to replace `5` and `6` with named constants like `DicePerPlayer` and `DiceSides`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking again the problem was my factorial function didn't have a proper result for 0, so this fixes it

```
public static double Factorial(double num) 
            { 
                if(num == 0)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                for(int i = (int)num - 1; i > 0; i--) 
                {
                    num *= i;
                }
                return num;
            }
```

Comment: For style points, consider using recursion to define the `Factorial` method.